# How to bypass user authentication for vision api text detection OCR?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have an Android application that includes a feature for capturing ID card details by taking a photo. This functionality uses Google Vision API’s Text Detection.
Currently, if I share this application with another user, I need to grant them permission in the Google Console under IAM & Admin for them to use the OCR functionality. I want to avoid this requirement so that any user of my application can use the OCR functionality without needing specific permissions in the Google Console.

i have tried creating service account and using that in the application but that still needs authentication of user